# Lack-of-oxygen ways of dying

Tags: verbs, synonyms

What are the verbs describing the kind of deaths caused by lack of oxygen?

(For example to **suffocate**, to **smother**, to **drown**..)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Do you just want a list of words related to suffocation?

Answer (score 3):

The general/generic term for lack of oxygen is *asphyxiation* which you can put through any online thesaurus as a starting point - anything more specific would answer the question how oxygen was lost (*drown*, *choke*, *suffocate*, etc.)